# Broadcom Bluetooth device remains undetected (BCM2046, WIDCOMM )

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, broadcom

[image]

**lspci** output :

> Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)

**lsusb** output :

> Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)

**rfkill list** output :

1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth

Soft blocked: no

Hard blocked: no

## ..but my WiFi works fine.

In Windows I had to install [Dell Wirless 365 Bluetooth](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails/Product/inspiron-15-intel-n5010?driverId=K1MFY&osCode=W764&fileId=2731097154) driver to get it working.
I installed **BlueMan** in Ubuntu, but it doesn't show any Bluetooth adapter.
When I try to apply a kernel patch described [here](http://www.mindwerks.net/2011/11/wireless-bcm4312-3-2-kernel/) , it ends up saying:

> patching file src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c
>
> Hunk #1 FAILED at 332.
>
> 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c.rej

## Thanks for any help...

Comment: Have you updates all drivers correctly?

Comment: Yeah did, using jockey-gtk

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I believe this may be caused by THIS bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/714862

Comment: Good news to you. My bluetooth never worked in ages and I share the exact same chipset as yours. If you are dualbooting like me, you should upgrade your drivers in Windows. If you need assistance and link to latest drivers, etc. add details regarding your exact make (Mine was Dell 14R N4010) and I'll write an answer for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I really don't want to boot into Windows...
My one is Dell Inspiron N5010. Thanks!

Comment: @Naveen Unfortunately, the only way I know of for fixing this is if you update your Windows Bluetooth drivers. No other suggestion that I can offer you. Good luck.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/845531/no-bluetooth-adapters-found-on-ubuntu-16-04 Check the answer here, I got it working finally, had a similar problem to yours

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my dual boot machine, switching over to windows and enabling the bluetooth and then going back to Ubuntu 12.04 fixed the problem.

Comment: Is it a matter of enabling it at the BIOS level?

Comment: This worked for me