# modprobe bluez module not found

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

On trying sudo apt-get install bluez on Ubuntu 12.04, I receive the following messages - 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
bluez is already the newest version.

when I try modprobe bluez I am receiving "FATAL: Module bluez not found." message. 
How do I enable bluez, as My Program is not able to find the Bluetooth device?

Any Help appreciated, Thanks in advance,
Padma

Answer (score 0):

The kernel module is called *bluetooth*, but I doubt loading it manually will help. I'd grep the device Id with *lspci* or *lsusb* and google for it. Some devices are not supported by (specific versions of) Linux.

Comment: Thanks. I tried grepped bluetooth lspci and there was no output. but when i tried with lsusb- I am recieving Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)

Comment: Looks like you're out of luck. BCM2046 is some weird device other people on [Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/193482/broadcom-bluetooth-device-remains-undetected-bcm2046-widcomm) or [Arch](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=130995) failed to get running as a bluetooth device.

Comment: Hi all,
Thanks for your help. the issue was solved by turning Bluetooth adapter on in Windows.